# Python. Get a list with weeks

Tags: python

I have a range of dates. For instance:
from 2020-09-28
until 2020-10-13.
And I need to get a list of weeks starting from Mondays with dates.
For instance:

```
[['2020-09-28', '2020-10-04'], ['2020-10-05', '2020-10-11'], ['2020-10-12', ' 2020-10-14 ']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to print Weekday,hope it will help

```
import datetime 
import calendar
def findDay(date):
    for i in date:
        born = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%d-%m-%Y').weekday() 
        return (calendar.day_name[born])

  # Driver program 
date = ["24-3-2020"]
print(findDay(date))
```

[image]